# Mocking a custom annotation validation in Java

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, validation, annotations, mockito

How to properly mock custom validation annotations?

So I created a custom @interface and the corresponding validator class.
Inside the validator class, I call an external api to check if the value of the annotated attribute in my DTO is valid or not.

I have something like:

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValueValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomValidator{
    String message() default "invalid value";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal=true, level=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ValueValidator implements 
  ConstraintValidator<MyCustomValidator, String> {

    ExternalApi externalApi;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyCustomValidator object) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value,
      ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        
      if(!externalApi.validate(value))
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    }

}
```

```java
@Data
@Valid
public class myDTORequest {

   @MyCustomValidator
   private String myAttribute;
}
```

I use mockmvc to test my controller. Now it is failing because the external api is null/unreachable.
Is there a way I could mock @MyCustomValidator so that it does not try to call an external api? Or better, mock the ExternalApi call inside the validator?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `@MockBean`?

Comment: is your externalAPI an autowired component?  If so, use `@MockBean` or `@SpyBean` if you wish to mock partially only.  

I am curious as to what exactly is this ExternalAPI and why does it exists inside your ConstraintValidator.

Comment: @SMA it's constructor injected via RequiredArgsConstructor. Basically, the external api accepts a value, and checks if it's a valid value for a certain set (ie: List of available currencies).